# locusts-plugins: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: selenium, locust

I've installed the locusts-plugins along with the other required modules as shown in the setup.py:
"locust>=1.4.3",
"psycogreen",
"psycopg2-binary",
"websocket-client",
"python-dateutil",
"pymongo",
"confluent-kafka",
"selenium>=4.0.0.b2",
"lxml",
"opencensus-ext-azure"
But when I attempt to run any of the examples using the webdrivers I get the error:
File "c:\users\mjohns33\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\subprocess.py", line 1270, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
2021-04-12T20:11:44Z <Greenlet at 0x55012d0: > failed with FileNotFoundError
I have the standalone server running and chromedriver in the path, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The actual error: 
  File "c:\users\userID\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\gevent\subprocess.py", line 1270, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Arent there more lines in the callstack? The ones you posted dont say what line of locust/locust-plugins code actually failed. Did you install packages manually somehow? All you should need to do is pip install locust-plugins

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the full callstack. The command that it is complaining about is `killall`, which is not available on Windows.

I've only ever run WebdriverUser on Mac and Linux. It might work if you just comment out that line (c:\users\mjohns33\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\locust_plugins\users\webdriver.py, line 127)

(and manually kill chromedriver as needed)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the locust-plugins is all-inclusive, meaning you don't want to install selenium or any other modules. Python, locust and locust-plugins, that's it.
I still see new errors but just having what's needed clears up a lot of these issues.